# Deleting watermark in Word from Excel VBA (redux) Difference between Word & Excel VBA

Tags: excel, ms-word, watermark, vba

[There is another recent question with a similar title that has not yet been answered satisfactorily, and gave me no insight :-( ]

This is my first attempt to integrate a little Word automation with Excel VBA, so I started with a macro recording in Word VBA to have a clue. Unfortunately, when I try to translate this into Excel, even making allowances for having to use the Excel local **wrdDoc** to qualify references, the code that works in Word VBA does not work from Excel VBA. Deeply frustrating.

Here is the recorded code snippet from Word that I started with:
*[Shape name manually edited after recording to match assigned name for the Watermark image]*

```
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Select
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes("US-CA watermark").Select
Selection.Delete
```

Here is the code snippet from Excel I derived from that:
*[sWatermark string predefined to match the picture name]*

```
With wrdDoc
    .Sections(1).Range.Select
    .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    .Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes(sWatermark).Select
    .Selection.Delete
End With
```

Result: VBA chokes every time when I try to select the watermark (line 3 within the With block).

I have tried the problem line with and without the . prefix [i.e. as wrdDoc.Selection and just Selection (as in the original Word macro) ].

I have tried accessing the watermark as .HeaderFooter.shapes(1) after verifying that there is only 1 item in the range. Again, this seems to work quite satisfactorily in Word VBA, but never in Excel VBA.

WHY?!?!?!

Comment: `.Selection` should be `.Application.Selection`

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using the Selection when possible, as it can be changed during macro execution. For example:

```
wrdDoc.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryHeaderStory).ShapeRange(1).Delete
```

Comment: I know to try to avoid Selection in general, though I have found in the past that VBA can be very unforgiving of that. FOr instance, even here, I tried to dispense with the .Sections(1).Range.select and meld the first two lines, but failed miserably at that, too.      Also, your admonition doesn't seem to answer the question anyway, as to why VBA code works within Word but the equivalent does not work in Excel.

Comment: @Alister `Selection` refers to `Application.Selection`, but in the second code to `wrdDoc.Selection` and there is no `Document.Selection` property

Comment: if you can add reference to Microsoft Word and `Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document`, you should get compile error on the `wrdDoc.Selection` line(s)